# overlap silent video with video and audio

Tags: premiere, video-editor, audio, adobe

I am new to video editing so excuse me if I am using wrong words to describe my question.
I am trying to make a video clip in adobe premier pro with two videos. First one  has no audio attached. Second video has. SO what I wanted to do is to make a small second video playing with background of first video(like 2 videos on the one screen but 1st on the background). But when I am doing:

1. place 1st video on V1
2. place 2nd video on V2 -- it places without audio

But when I am doing

1. place 2nd video on V1 -- it places with audio
2. move it to V2
3. place 1st video on V1.

Audio from 2nd video doesnt disappear....

And I can not understand how to avoid 2nd way of doing it and still keep audio from 2nd video.
I mean I can use this 2nd way but it is so uncomfortable if I will want to add more video in addition to 2nd one.

Comment: What MoritzLost said, but also you can alt/option click on either the sound or video of a linked clip and it will just select the sound or video, meaning you can move or delete it independently. Recommend you follow the link to the support pages and have a bit of a read.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use to control where clips are placed is **Source Patching** and **Track Targeting**. Those are two of the small indicators to the left of the timeline tracks. Track Targeting has a couple of functions, in general it controls which tracks varied editing operations can affect. For example, if you paste clips from the clipboard, the pasted video and audio will be placed on the lowest active (targeted) audio and video track respectively.

If you want to control where the clips from your Project Panel go, you can use Source Patching instead. Only one audio and video track respectively can be the activated at a time in the Source Patching column, and those will be the tracks that new material is placed into by default.

You can find more info on that on the [Adobe support pages](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/source-patching-track-targetting.html).

[image: Source Patching & Track Targeting]